# R how to add a value to a df by name of ro and name of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, row

Hopefully there is a quick answer to this, I've been puzzling over it for a bit of time now.

```
bp="300"
cur_sample="10_n1"

# PRINTS WHAT AT THIS POSITION BY ROW NAME AND COL NAME
FGA_matrix[cur_sample,bp]
[1] NA

# RETURNS AN ERROR
FGA_matrix[cur_sample,bp]=1
Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
‘max’ not meaningful for factors
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors

#HOWEVER
FGA_matrix[,as.character(bp)]=1
FGA_matrix[,as.character(bp)]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

# SO WE CAN ASSIGN VALUES BASED ON COL NAME

# BUT IT DOESN'T WORK FOR ROW NAMES
> FGA_matrix[cur_sample,]=1
Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
‘max’ not meaningful for factors
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
```

Does anyone know how to assign values to the df based on row names? I'm sure there is a quick answer to this but my google searches are coming up a bit vacant.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT; Here is the top of the dataframe as requested:

```
> FGA_matrix[1:10,1:10]
          300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309
10_n1     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10_n2     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10_n3     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
11_n1     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
11_n2     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
11_n3     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12_18_n1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12_18_n2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12_18_n3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12_4_n1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: `FGA_matrix[rownames(FGA_matrix)==cur_sample,]=1`

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `dput(FGA_matrix)`. Or, if it is too long with the output of `dput(head(FGA_matrix, 20))`.

Comment: FGA_matrix[rownames(FGA_matrix)==cur_sample,]=1 this works to assign the entire row to the value of 1. Apologies if I wasn't clear but I am really looking to edit values by row and column simultaneously so I can edit each value by rowname and colname. I am populating this df with values from another in a loop. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Based on Onyambu's answer:

```
> FGA_matrix[rownames(FGA_matrix)==cur_sample,as.character(bp)]=5
> FGA_matrix[1:10,1:10]
         300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309
10_n1      5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10_n2     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10_n3     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  N
```

A